# Avoid read file being the alternate buffer in Vim

Tags: vim, neovim

I am having an issue with Vim, NeoVim in this case if it makes a difference. I have an `autocmd` that includes a boilerplate when creating a file of a certain type, a Vue file in this case. Here is the code:

```
autocmd BufNewFile *.vue silent! 0r ~/.dotfiles/skeletons/vue-pug-scss.vue
```

This simple thing works great except when using `CTRL-^` it goes back to the boilerplate file and I don't want this. I don't want the boilerplate file to be in my history of visited files so to speak.

I've tried many things but I struggle to understand how the buffer list works together with `CTRL-^`. The thing is that if I run `:ls`, the boilerplate file does not appear even though it is what I get when doing `CTRL-^`. It only appears in `:ls` once I've been back on it.

What I thought would work is to add `| bd#` but it says no buffer was deleted. When I am on the newly created file, `:bd#` does not work whereas `:b#` works. This sounds completely illogical to me, or inconsistent at best. Although I am probably mixing up an alternate buffer and previous buffer or something.

Does anybody know how I can make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have two sub-questions:

> I don't want the boilerplate file to be in my history of visited files so to speak.

Some possible options in no particular order

1. Avoid using `:h :read` command in favor of `:h readfile()` and `:h append()` or such;
2. Remove `a` from `:h 'cpoptions'`;
3. Prepend `:h :keepalt` to your command.

Note that 3) still creates a new buffer, although it doesn't become the alternate one.

> The thing is that if I run :ls, the boilerplate file does not appear

> When I am on the newly created file, :bd# does not work whereas :b# works. This sounds completely illogical to me, or inconsistent at best.

A buffer in Vim has boolean states of "loaded" and "listed". Both are independent one from another.

`:h :ls` only shows "listed" buffers by default. To see "unlisted" buffers too one has to type `:ls!`

`:h :bdelete` changes buffer state to be "unlisted" and "unloaded" at the same time. As your buffer is already "unlisted" and "unloaded" you've got `:h E516`. You may use `:h :bwipeout` to remove a buffer completely, but in this case pressing `:h CTRL-^` will result in `:h E23` error. To set new alternate buffer you can type `:let @# = 42`, where `42` is some *existing* buffer number or name. Alternatively, `:balt foobar` can create a new *unloaded* and *listed* buffer named *foobar* and set it as the alternate one.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I managed to find out about `keepalt` in the meantime. But I went for the `set cpoptions-=a` solution.

Answer (score 2):

From `:help :read`, emphasis mine:

> If a file name is given with ":r", it becomes the alternate file.  This can be
> used, for example, when you want to edit that file instead: ":e! #".  **This can
> be switched off by removing the 'a' flag from the 'cpoptions' option**.

Comment: Thank you this works fine. I didn't go this far down into `:read` help. I think I managed to do something similar with another thing I've found in the help called "keepalt". But I prefer your solution. Now I am having a related issue because I have a [No Name] buffer which becomes my alternate on startup. I think it may be created by a plugin deprecation warning.

Comment: That `[No Name]` buffer is a separate issue, unrelated to the solution suggested here.

Comment: Yes `set nohidden` has fixed this for me as suggested on neovim's GitHub to me.